# Want ValidationRule to keep focus

Tags: c#, wpf, validationrule

I am setting up a binding on a TextBox, and the text cannot be blank (null, whitespace or otherwise).  I set up a ValidationRule as below:

```
internal class CannotBeBlankTextboxRule : ValidationRule
{
    public String ErrorText { get; set; } = "The text cannot be blank.";

    public override ValidationResult Validate (Object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var str = value as String;

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
            return (new ValidationResult(false, this.ErrorText));

        return (new ValidationResult(true, null));
    }
}
```

It is working fine, but the window allows the user to click elsewhere and continue even though this error is there.

Is there a way I can keep the TextBox from losing focus while the validation is failing?

Comment: It is not a good decision to disable moving the focus away from an UI element. Maybe you would better disable all other controls or the accept button, or provide some wizard-like UI for your task.

Comment: Thanks but I know what I'm doing.